# Remove the [feature] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, meta, retag-request

The [[feature]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature) tag seems to be used for two things:

- Instead of or as well as the `feature-request` tag.
- For discussing something that's a feature.

Both of these seem pointless to me, as the first one already has a tag and the second is too vague to be useful.

Comment: BUG: I tried to suggest [feature] as a synonym for [bug], but the system wouldn't let me...

Comment: @Shog9: That in itself is a feature.

Answer (score 2):

Agree. [feature] tag was burninated.

This is meta-only by the way, though I suspect it's of similar low value on Stack Overflow because it is so inherently vague...

Answer (score 0):

It was really confusing when they went to the `featured` tag on the new sites.  Why would you change a paradigm like that?

It appears that they meant the `featured` tag to bring emphasis to a post by the moderators, but it has certainly been confusing from the beginning.

Maybe they could find a different tag for emphasis, like `Hot Post` or something.

Comment: Are you confusing the [feature], the [featured], and the [feature-request] tags? Because I still saw the [feature-request] tag on every new SE 2.0 meta site that I've looked at. And [featured] is a completely different system altogether.

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/tags/feature-request

Comment: @Grace, I guarantee you I'm confused.  I have no idea what they all mean.  Looking, I see that the feature tag has disappeared on the Metas.  I see now what they were driving at, but it's not worth the confusion.